# Calculate the total price from a foreach generated table in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following code :

```
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    // alert(data[i].stock_id);
    html1 += '<tr>\n\
            <td><input type="text" style="width:80px !important;" readonly id="patient_name' + i + '" name="patient_name[]" value="'+data[i].patient_name+'"/></td>\n\
            <td><input type="text" style="width:80px !important;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="description' + i + '" name="description[]" value="'+data[i].description+'"/></td>\n\\n\n\
            <td><input type="text" style="width:80px !important;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="amount' + i + '" name="amount[]" value="'+data[i].amount+'"/></td>\n\
            <td><input type="text" style="width:80px !important;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="qauntity' + i + '" name="quantity[]" value="'+data[i].quantity+'"/></td>\n\
            <td><input type="text" style="width:80px !important;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="charged'+i+'" name="charged[]" value="'+data[i].charged+'"></td> \n\
            <td><input type="hidden" style="width:80px !important;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="patient_visit_statement_id'+i+'" name="patient_visit_statement_id[]" value="'+data[i].patient_visit_statement_id+'"></td> \n\
            <td><input type="hidden" style="width:80px color:red!important ;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="patient_id'+i+'" name="patient_payment_id[]" value="'+data[i].patient_payment_id+'"></td> \n\\n\
            <td><input type="hidden" style="width:80px !important;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="patient_id'+i+'" name="patient_id[]" value="'+data[i].patient_id+'"></td> \n\
            <td><input type="hidden" style="width:80px color:red!important ;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="visit_id'+i+'" name="visit_id[]" value="'+data[i].visit_id+'"></td> \n\n\
    </tr> ';

} 
htmlhead1+='\n\
    <th style="width:80px !important;" >Patient Name</th>\n\
    <th style="width:80px !important;" >  Description</th> \n\
    <th style="width:80px !important;" > Amount </th> \n\
    <th style="width:80px !important;" >Quantity</th> \n\
    <th style="width:80px !important;" >Charged? </th> \n \n \n';

$('#tbody1').empty();
$('#tbody1').append(htmlhead1);
$('#tbody1').append(html1);
$('#tbody1').append(total_price);
```

The for loop forms populates a dynamic list in a table of values from the Database, I want to sum the  value of amount and view it as total amount/price.
How can I calculate the  total sum of amount from the  loop and append it to the  #tbody1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have somewhere you add up the individual values​​. On it you'll need only add that the cycle of what you have there only addition.

Before your cycle for

```
   var total_amount=0;
   var total_quantity=0;
```

and then add to it

```
total_amount+=data[i].amount;
total_quantity+=data[i].quantity;
```

And then you just need to compile TOTAL_PRICE and to insert these variables

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
var amountTotal = 0;
    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        amountTotal += data[i].amount;
        // alert(data[i].stock_id);
        html1 += '<tr>\n\
                <td><input type="text" style="width:80px !important;" readonly id="patient_name' + i + '" name="patient_name[]" value="'+data[i].patient_name+'"/></td>\n\
                <td><input type="text" style="width:80px !important;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="description' + i + '" name="description[]" value="'+data[i].description+'"/></td>\n\\n\n\
                <td><input type="text" style="width:80px !important;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="amount' + i + '" name="amount[]" value="'+data[i].amount+'"/></td>\n\
                <td><input type="text" style="width:80px !important;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="qauntity' + i + '" name="quantity[]" value="'+data[i].quantity+'"/></td>\n\
                <td><input type="text" style="width:80px !important;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="charged'+i+'" name="charged[]" value="'+data[i].charged+'"></td> \n\
                <td><input type="hidden" style="width:80px !important;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="patient_visit_statement_id'+i+'" name="patient_visit_statement_id[]" value="'+data[i].patient_visit_statement_id+'"></td> \n\
                <td><input type="hidden" style="width:80px color:red!important ;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="patient_id'+i+'" name="patient_payment_id[]" value="'+data[i].patient_payment_id+'"></td> \n\\n\
                <td><input type="hidden" style="width:80px !important;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="patient_id'+i+'" name="patient_id[]" value="'+data[i].patient_id+'"></td> \n\
                <td><input type="hidden" style="width:80px color:red!important ;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="visit_id'+i+'" name="visit_id[]" value="'+data[i].visit_id+'"></td> \n\n\
        </tr> ';

    }
```

And finally print amount using amountTotal  by appending in `htmlhead1`

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
var myData = [1,2,3];

var myTotal = 0;  //Variable to hold your total

for(var i=0, len=myData.length; i<len; i++){
    myTotal += myData[i];  
}

alert(myTotal); // 6
```

Fiddle Demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/rN5m3/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code :-**

```
var total=0;
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    total+=data[i].amount;
    html1 += '<tr>\n\
            <td><input type="text" style="width:80px !important;" readonly id="patient_name' + i + '" name="patient_name[]" value="'+data[i].patient_name+'"/></td>\n\
            <td><input type="text" style="width:80px !important;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="description' + i + '" name="description[]" value="'+data[i].description+'"/></td>\n\\n\n\
            <td><input type="text" style="width:80px !important;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="amount' + i + '" name="amount[]" value="'+data[i].amount+'"/></td>\n\
            <td><input type="text" style="width:80px !important;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="qauntity' + i + '" name="quantity[]" value="'+data[i].quantity+'"/></td>\n\
            <td><input type="text" style="width:80px !important;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="charged'+i+'" name="charged[]" value="'+data[i].charged+'"></td> \n\
            <td><input type="hidden" style="width:80px !important;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="patient_visit_statement_id'+i+'" name="patient_visit_statement_id[]" value="'+data[i].patient_visit_statement_id+'"></td> \n\
            <td><input type="hidden" style="width:80px color:red!important ;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="patient_id'+i+'" name="patient_payment_id[]" value="'+data[i].patient_payment_id+'"></td> \n\\n\
            <td><input type="hidden" style="width:80px !important;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="patient_id'+i+'" name="patient_id[]" value="'+data[i].patient_id+'"></td> \n\
            <td><input type="hidden" style="width:80px color:red!important ;" readonly class="SmallInput" id="visit_id'+i+'" name="visit_id[]" value="'+data[i].visit_id+'"></td> \n\n\
    </tr> ';

} 
html1 += '<tr>\n\
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="total_ans">    
      </td>  
</tr>';


var textBox = document.getElementById("total_ans");
textBox.value = total.toString();;
```

By this code you can get the total answer and append the answer in tbody.

I hope it will helpful to you..